# How to get plus sign in query string of an url

Tags: java, python, url, request

I have a web application where I have required to get plus sign in query string of an url.

for example : we have an url like http://www.example.com/?q=a+b

Now I need **a+b** value of request param **q** in our codebase.

What is the best way to do the same

Comment: The plus sign is a metacharacter in URLs.  If you want a literal plus sign you must urlencode it as `%2B`

Comment: There are too many tags on your question: do you want to get this using java or python?

Comment: @StephaneM : Any language (Would prefer Java)

Comment: you mean if '+' in url , you want to get that string which contain that '+' ?